# What is the difference between Solr Replication and Solr Cloud?

Tags: solr, replication, solr4, solrcloud, sunspot-solr

I'm supporting on rails project, which contain rails app and additional instance with Solr.

My environment: rails 3.2.1, ruby 2.1.2, sunspot 2.1.0, Solr 4.1.6.

**Problem:**

Clould provider is not stable. I cannot use other cloud provider - it is customer's demand. Oftentimes search server goes on maintenance and web application stop working on production. So, I think about how to make 2 identical search servers instead of one, to make system more stable: if one server will be down, other will continue working.

**Way out of trouble:**

- or configure two search servers as [Solr Replication](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication)
- or configure two search servers as [SolrCloud](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrCloud)

**Question:**

1. What to do and why?
2. Is SolrCloud is better solution?
3. What is PROC and CONS of these variants?
4. In which cases is better to coose SolrCloud?
5. In which cases is better to coose Solr Replication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to find may comparisons for Solr Master Slave Heirarchy Vs SolrCloud in forums, but these are my understandings/experience from them, so consume it lightly.

1. What to do and why?
   This depends purely on your business requirement. I would say if your application just reads data from SOLR and need high availability on reading data from SOLR then a simple one master to many slave hierarchy is more than sufficient.
   But if you are looking out for high availability on writing to SOLR too, then SolrCloud is a right option
2. Is SolrCloud is better solution?
   There is nothing like better, maintaining SolrCloud needs a good infrastructure and have to look out the availability of ZooKeepers, and nodes health, high performance disk for better replication speed etc.
   But, other than this we don't need to worry about Data consistency among nodes as this will be taken care by SolrCloud
3. What is PROC and CONS of these variants?
   As described above.
4. In which cases is better to coose SolrCloud?
   When you need high availability on Solr Writes as well as reads, we have to go for SolrCloud
   Also, if you cannot afford bigger machines to have one single node, then you can split your index to shards and keep it under smaller config machines.
5. In which cases is better to choose Solr Replication?
   When your application does not write in real time to SOLR, Replication is enough and no need to get complicated with SolrCloud. Also, its comparatively easy to setup Master Slave than SolrCloud