# How to setup Solr Replication with two search servers?

Tags: solr, replication, solr4, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

Hi I'm developing rails project with sunspot solr and configure Solr replication.
My environment: rails 3.2.1, ruby 2.1.2, sunspot 2.1.0, Solr 4.1.6.

Why replication: I need more stable system - oftentimes search server goes on maintenance and web application stop working on production. So, I think about how to make 2 identical search servers instead of one, to make system more stable: if one server will be down, other will continue working.

I cannot find any good turtorial with simple, easy to understand and described in details turtorial...
I'm trying to set up replication on two servers, but I do not fully understand how replication working inside:

- synchronize data between two servers (is it automatic action?)
- balances search requests between two servers
- when one server suddenly stop working other should become a master (is it automatic action?)
- is there replication features other than listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to this is similar to 
[How to setup Solr Cloud with two search servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766474/how-to-setup-solr-cloud-with-two-search-servers)
[What is the difference between Solr Replication and Solr Cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766288/what-is-the-difference-between-solr-replication-and-solr-cloud)

Can we close this as duplicate?